# Prove $X^*$ is reflexive then $X$ is reflexive

Tags: functional-analysis

Prove $X^*$ is reflexive then $X$ is reflexive

**My attempt:**
Let $J : X \to X^{**}$ and $J_*: X^* \to X^{***}$ be the canonical injections. Suppose by contradiction that $X$ isn't reflexive, then exists $f\in X^{**}$ such that for all $x\in X$  such that $J(x)=f$, in other words:
$J(X)\not \subset X^{**}$

Here i'm stuck, can someone help me?

Comment: If you prove that reflexivity $X^\ast$ follows from reflexivity $X$, then your statement will turn out as a simple consequence.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $X^*$ is reflexive, prove that $J^*\colon X^{***} \to X^*$, the dual of $J$, has to be the inverse of $J_*$. In particular, $J^*$ is an isomorphism. Deduce that $J$ has to be an isomorphism.